# Issue with re-initializing typeahead

Tags: typeahead.js

This is my requirement: I need a user input text box, when user enters some text it has to show suggestions from local data as well as remote data (results comes from server based on input text). when user re-enters different text it has to search again in local and again a call to server to get new data.

I tried using twitter typeahead. Initially I was able to show suggestions from local as well as remote data but only once as typeahead doesn't make another remote call as it already has prefetched data in its memory. Then I tried destorying and re-initializing typeahead on each user input (only if user input is different from previous one, this check is already there). But I am getting below error:

"TypeError: this.$menu is null"

Can anybody tell me what can be cause of this issue? Below are my code samples (these are from a test page I created to sort out the problem):

**typeahead initialization property -**

```
var props = {
            template:'<div>{{name}}_{{id}}</div>',
            local:[
                {id:"val1", name:"india"},
                {id:"val2", name:"indiana"},
                {id:"val3", name:"abcindjgaja"}
            ],
            limit:10000,
            valueKey:'name',
            cache:false,
            remote:{
                url:<MYURL>,
                beforeSend:function (jqXHR, settings) {
                    settings.url += $("#myTI").val();  //myTI is id of input text box
                },
                filter:function (data) {
                    var dataSet = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if ((data[i].name.toLowerCase()).indexOf($("#myTI").val().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                            dataSet.push({
                                name:data[i].name,
                                id:data[i].id
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    return dataSet;
                }
            },
            engine:{
                compile:function (template) {
                    return {
                        render:function (ctx) {
                            var temp = Handlebars.compile(template);
                            return temp(ctx);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

**Logic for initializing/re-initializing -**

```
$("#myTI").keyup((function () {
            return function (e) {
                if (window[window.text]) {
                    clearTimeout(window[window.text]);
                }
                window.text = $("#myTI").val();
                window[window.text] = window.setTimeout(process, 250);

                function process() {
                    var dataFound = false;
                    for (var key in window.dataMap) {
                        if (!window.dataMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (window.text.indexOf(key) != -1) {
                            dataFound = true;
                            window.dataSetName = window.dataMap[key];
                            updateTypeahead();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!dataFound) {
                        window.dataSetName = "typeahead" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000, 10);
                        window.dataMap[window.text] = window.dataSetName;
                        updateTypeahead();
                    }
                }
            }
        }()));
        if (!window.tyepahead) {
            updateTypeahead();
        }

        function updateTypeahead() {
            if (window.tyepahead) {
                window.tyepahead.typeahead('destroy');
            }
            props.name = window.dataSetName;
            window.tyepahead = $("#myTI").typeahead(props);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think destroy and reinitialize is not needed in your case. Just force the typeahead not to cache the `remote` call (you are putting `cache: false` in wrong place):

```
var props = {
    template:'<div>{{name}}_{{id}}</div>',
    local: [
        {id:"val1", name:"india"},
        {id:"val2", name:"indiana"},
        {id:"val3", name:"abcindjgaja"}
    ],
    limit: 10000,
    valueKey: 'name',
    remote: {
        url: <MYURL>,
        cache: false, // move cache: false to here
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            settings.url += $("#myTI").val();  //myTI is id of input text box
        },
        filter: function (data) {
            var dataSet = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if ((data[i].name.toLowerCase()).indexOf($("#myTI").val().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                    dataSet.push({
                        name:data[i].name,
                        id:data[i].id
                    });
                }
            }
            return dataSet;
        }
    },
    engine: {
        compile:function (template) {
            return {
                render:function (ctx) {
                    var temp = Handlebars.compile(template);
                    return temp(ctx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/LPgv5/1/

Hope it helps.